# Nokogiri only get list items with links first

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have a document that looks like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/Synergies">Link</a>Content
  </li>
  </li>
    Content <a href="/Synergies">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to only obtain the list items that start with an `<a>` tag, i.e. the first `<li>` would be a hit but the second would not.

I tried getting all list items and regex matching on the html content but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
list.search('li').each do |item|
  if /^<a href="\/Synergies".*$/.match(item) 
    puts link # hit?
  end
end
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the item's first child is either not text or empty text:

```rb
list.search('li').each do |item|
  if !item.children.first.text? || item.children.first.text.strip.empty?
    puts item # hit?
  end
end
```

If you want to exclude items that don't begin with a link, you can select the first child and check its parents in the condition:

```rb
list.search('li > a:first-child').each do |item|
  if !item.parent.children.first.text? || item.parent.children.first.text.strip.empty?
    puts item # hit?
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't check for a link though.

Comment: I added a second example that explicitly checks for links.

Comment: the first example accomplished what I needed – my bad for the confusion in the question